# VBA getting error Active method of Worksheet class failed

Tags: vba, excel, methods

I tried to look for answers but am not finding anything that has worked so far.  I have some code that works for some people and doesn't work for others (using same version of Excel) when running this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
Sheets("Discount").Activate
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="01"    
ActiveSheet.Range("G14:O15,O18:O19,D29:I29,D31:I31,D33:I33,D35:I35,D37:I37").ClearContents
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Option Button 31").ControlFormat.Value = xlOn
OptionButton31_Click
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The error shows up at Sheets.("Discount").Activate

the spelling of the worksheet is correct.  I also tried

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="01"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Discount").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="01"    
ActiveSheet.Range("G14:O15,O18:O19,D29:I29,D31:I31,D33:I33,D35:I35,D37:I37").ClearContents
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Option Button 31").ControlFormat.Value = xlOn
OptionButton31_Click 
ActiveWorkbook.Protect Password:="01"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

And still getting the error.  I am having a hard time figuring it out because it works for me every time, but doesn't for other people.

Comment: Can you try leaving ScreenUpdating on to see if anything strange is happening while you step through the code on the affected users' machines?

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1:**

Instead of `Sheets.("Discount").Activate` write `Sheets("Discount").Activate` and it should work. E.g., remove the dot.

**Solution 2:**

If this does not work, try to make sure that this sheet is visible. E.g. write before the line with the error the following:

`Sheets("Discount").Visible = True`

---

In general, in VBA try to avoid `ActiveSheet`, `ActiveWorkbook`, `ActiveCell` -
 [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

As noted by @Mat's Mug, consider using `Worksheets("Discount").Visible`, when you refer to Worksheets, because the `Sheets` collection contains `Charts` as well.

Comment: Also you should use the `Worksheets` collection if you're expecting to work on a `Worksheet`. The `Sheets` collection also contains charts.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - that's true.

Comment: For solution 1 the dot was not there, it was s mistype in comments but code was clean, so unfortunately that did not help.  for Solution 2, that worksheet is always visible, because it works like a user form.  I need it to be an active worksheet when the file is opened by a user.  I may have just thought of a solution, maybe I will write the activate and rest of this as separate macro and just refer to that macro on open.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

Sheets("Discount").Visible
Sheets("Discount").Select

If this doesn't work, let me know and I'll see if there's anything else I can recommend. If you make a note of any error messages, this may help. Also, try running it with screenupdating not turned off as the person above suggested - then you will see if there's a specific action that's making it fall over.